# Dependency resolution take too much time. How to reduce?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-resolution

Gradle build report html showed the `Dependency Resolution` total time over 30s for every time I run my `app` no matter how many things I modified. I feel it is unreasonable to take so long time for resolving dependencies for each time I run, cause the dependencies of the project is even never change.

Gradle version: 2.10

Android plugin version: 2.1.0

Would be better to don't change the version.

Part of the report:

[image]

By the way: why `debugAssemble` task contains some tasks or dependencies like `releaseXXX`? Needs to exclude manually?